# Change CRS of .tif file using gdal command

Tags: tiff, qgis, osgeo

I am trying to change the CRS of a `.tif` file using `gdalwarp` in the OSGeo4W command prompt. Before I would do it manually in QGIS by `Export > Save As > Set CRS`. However I have a lot of files so I want to automate it. Here is the command:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 in.tif out.tif
```

However I get this error message:

```
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: prime meridian not found
Creating output file that is 190P x 140L.
```

What am I missing? I've looked through the documentation but am unable to find another command that would solve this.

EDIT: I tried to add the -s_srs in the command:
`gdalwarp -s_srs '+proj=merc +lon_0=-115.75 +lat_ts=33.3 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs' -t_srs EPSG:4326 in.tif out.tif`

I get the error:

```
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create: unrecognized format / unknown name
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
'+proj=merc
```

Here is the CRS of the `in.tif`:

```
Unknown CRS: PROJCRS["WGS 1984. Custom Ellipsoid: Semi-major axis=6378137.000000, Semi-minor axis=6356752.314245.;scale=0.00100000000000000002,offset=0.00000000000000000000",BASEGEOGCRS["WGS_1984",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.25722356049,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],ID["EPSG",6326]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]]],CONVERSION["Mercator (variant B)",METHOD["Mercator (variant B)",ID["EPSG",9805]],PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",33.3,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8823]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-115.75,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8802]],PARAMETER["False easting",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8806]],PARAMETER["False northing",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["easting",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],AXIS["northing",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]] - Projected
```

Comment: What's the source CRS? What happens if you try to specify it explicitly with `-s_srs`?

Comment: I edited the question. Still got an error.